# setting timout for connection between server and client in java

Tags: java, sockets, timeout

My Server program waits for the Client for long time But I want the Server Socket to wait for the Client for only specified time limit, say 2 minutes.How can i set this time limit.I have used timeout on timeout on Server Socket which blocks the connection for the specified timeout Which is not desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method to set timeout in server socket : setSoTimeout(int timeout)

For more information read the documentation : [ServerSocket](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html)